# ETZ balance on myetherwallet

Tags: wallets

How do I check my ETZ balance on myetherwallet? I had ETH in there and there was a hard fork yesterday - will I not automatically get ETZ as well?

Answer (score 5):

You will automatically get ETZ based on the amount of ETH you have. However, how you move these is where it gets dangerous.

When Ethereum and Etheruem Classic forked, it took a while to get public nodes up and running and the community was much smaller and less scammy back then. We looked into it yesterday and could not find a single way to get a public node running and every application we came across was malicious.

For this reason, we are advising to stay away from this. Entering your private key onto their website or installing an exe from them will likely result in lost ETH and possibly a full system compromise.

Do not get greedy. Do not trust links. Do not trust anyone. Doing so will result in loss. If someone figures it out, it will be known. Until then, stay away.

More Information

- https://twitter.com/myetherwallet/status/954762712604528640
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2wLq_Ya3j8&feature=youtu.be&t=1

Answer (score 3):

According to [official ETZ website](https://www.etherzero.org/):

> 4. On 22th Jan, GET ETZ tutorials will be released

Yet, you should be careful. ETZ might be a scam project, so do not enter your private keys on any websites. At least before you transfer funds from your ETH account somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

https://wallet.etherzero.org/ is powered by MyEtherwallet? Since there is not one working exchange and the "scammy news" are actually negative at all and i would have to type in my privat key ... (THATs acutally ScamProof enough) you should srsly wait until there´s working masternode. Im actually mining with 1000 MH/s to their USA (only one) pool. Payments work but we cannot be sure that we get those ETZ afterall. For my part i do it the following way:

1) Holding ETZ on the only available Paper Wallet

2) Wait for at least 2 working exchanges (yobit disabled ETZ because of security reasons) and hope it wasnt "throughn outta window".

3) Wait for good news about ETZ. The Reputation is not good at all and the masterminds behind ETZ are not known enough. Maybe they are new in business and they maybe try. They could also use us miners to make them rich in the fast way. Since Cryptocurrencys has been hyped there are MUCH black sheeps around.

4) STOP Mining into their pool after 2 - 3 Weeks if there´s still not a sight of Masternode and transparency.

5) NOT ENTER ANY PRIVAT KEY TO WHEREEVER if it looks like a scam.